# Why is orthogonal weights initialization so important for PPO?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have implemented PPO to solve Atari environments. For the longest time I couldn't figure out why my model would not converge as fast as other open source solutions. Eventually it boiled down to this single weights initialization (in PyTorch) for the CNN:

`init_ = lambda m: init(m, nn.init.orthogonal_, lambda x: nn.init.constant_(x, 0), nn.init.calculate_gain("relu"))`

which is then applied to each of the layers. In other words, the neural network HAS to be initialized orthogonally. Once I added this, my model converges as expected.

Why is it that orthogonal initialization is so much superior to xavier initialization for PPO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this paper's ([Exact solutions to the nonlinear dynamics of learning in
deep linear neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6120.pdf)) result:

> Moreover, we introduce a mathematical condition for faithful backpropagation of error signals, namely dynamical isometry, and show, surprisingly that random scaled Gaussian
> initializations cannot achieve this condition despite their norm-preserving nature, while greedy pre-training
> and random orthogonal initialization can, thereby achieving depth independent learning times. Finally, we
> show that the property of dynamical isometry survives to good approximation even in extremely deep nonlinear random orthogonal networks operating just beyond the edge of chaos.

I think this is an answer to your question.